# What exactly are "More Games" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

The *Windows Features* dialog of Windows 7 includes an entry ambiguously named *"More Games"* as seen below. It does not seem to be present in Vista and I cannot find any mention of it through search engines.

Does anyone know exactly what it is or what games it includes?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will "install" a link to Microsoft for more games that you can play/purchase through MSN.

[image]

It should redirect you to the site http://www.microsoft.com/games/playyourgame/

Comment: Providing that "More Games from Microsoft" out-of-the-box would probably result in accusations of anti-competitive behavior.